# change an image via php dropdown

Tags: php, image, drop-down-menu

What I am trying to do is change the image when an item is selected from the drop down. This is part of a form so I cant have the value change. However the option value is the row id, that row would also contain the target for the image. But because the target 'file' is called outside the loop it isn't firing.

I read I have to call it within the loop first but can't get it to work. Could you look at the code below and throw me a hint?

Thanks

```
    <?php

include ("conned-db.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<select id='gallery_id' name='gallery_id' style='width:200px;' >";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
echo '<option value=' . $row['id'] . '>';
echo $row['gallery_name'];
echo '</option/>';
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td colspan='2' rowspan='2'>";
echo '<img src=' .$row['file']. '/></td>';

    ?>
```

Comment: you have to submit the form to the server for the value of the select to be available in php (it is a server side language). or use JS\AJAX

Comment: you'll need some javascript to do it.

Comment: @Dagon I don't think he needs it inside a form, he just wants a dynamic picture display based on selection.

Comment: The value of the drop-down needs to be submitted, but the image does not. Everything works fine except for .$row['file'] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work too. If the file locations of the images are available at the time you load the page using ajax is not a must. You have to use ajax if you need to query the server again to retrieve the required file location. The following code assumes that you have the location of the images for each item of the dropdown list at the time you load the page.

```
<select id='gallery_id' name='gallery_id' style='width:200px;' 
  onchange='document.getElementById("image").src=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title' >
 <?php
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
 {
  ?>
   <option value='<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>' title='<?php echo $row["file"]; ?>'> 
        <?php echo $row["gallery_name"]; ?>
   </option>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
<img id="image" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I think this is what you are looking for

If you want to do something like this you must use Ajax. Here you go for the link that helps you to understand about Ajax.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Note:

If you wanted it to be only PHP without Javascript, you would have to sacrifice the 'must not refresh' constraint, as the only way to submit the form is by pressing the button, and submitting the content.

Comment: OK thanks for the info, thought I'd have to do this with AJAX, just hoping that I could get away without it.

Comment: That's what i have mentioned in note. if you don't wanna use ajax then you should reload the page by submitting the form. Instead of $row['file'] place $_POST['gallery_id'] and $row['id'] as $row['file']

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example which implements java scrip and php where i update src of an image based on the id from the select you might want to change with specific src based on that id

```
<?php

    include ("conned-db.php");
    $item = $_GET["imageid"];
    if ($item == "")
    {
        $item = 1;
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery") 
    or die(mysql_error());  
   ?>
    <select id='gallery_id' name='gallery_id' onChange="window.location='file.php?imageid='+this.value" style='width:200px;' >
    <?

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
    {
    echo '<option value=' . $row['id'] . '>';
    echo $row['gallery_name'];
    echo '</option/>';
    }
  ?>
    </select>
    </td>
<?
    echo "<td colspan='2' rowspan='2'>";
?>
    <img src=' <?=$item?> '/></td>
```